# How to create Plans list using Html and Css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make this kind of **Plan list**.

[image: This plan list]

But somehow I'm still not able to achieve this I have created basic structure of this don't know how to make this complicated design as show in this picture?
Don't know how to create **cross-borders** after **INFINITY** I want create same type of structure using **HTML OR CSS**.

**Here is my code**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Price List</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS v5.0.2 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<style>
    .col-lg-2 {
        border: 1px solid black;
        background-color: red;

    }

    .col-lg-1 {
        background-color: red;
        border: 1px solid black;

    }

 

    div>.tx>p {
        margin-top: 19px;
    }
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center text-center">
        <div class="col-lg-2 bg-dark">
            <div>
                <h4>Random</h4>
                <br>
            </div>

            <div class="tx">
                <p> <span class="text-light"> Speed</span></p>
                <p> <span class="text-light"> Unlimited Data</span></p>
                <p> <span class="text-light"> Monthly rental</span></p>
                <p><span class="text-light">Who is it for?</span></p>


            </div>












        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-2 bg-danger">
            <div>
                <h5>INFINITY</h4>
                    <br>
            </div>

            <div class="tx">
                <p> <span class="text-light"> 1 Gbps</span></p>
                <p> <span class="text-light"> ✅ </span></p>
                <p> <span class="text-light"> ₹3999</span></p>
                <p><span class="text-light">Experts like <br>gamers,traders,<br>live streamers</span></p>


            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 bg-danger">
            <div>
                <h4>PROFESSIONAL</h4>
                <br>
            </div>

            <div class="tx">
                <p> <span class="text-light"> 300 Mbps</span></p>
                <p> <span class="text-light">✅ </span></p>
                <p> <span class="text-light">₹1499 </span></p>

                <p><span class="text-light">Professionals <br>Working <br>from home</span></p>


            </div>



























        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 bg-light ">
            <div>
                <h4>ENTERTAINMENT</h4>
                <br>
            </div>

            <div class="tx ">
                <p> <span class="text-dark"> 200 Mbps</span></p>
                <p> <span class="text-dark">✅ </span></p>
                <p> <span class="text-dark">₹999 </span></p>

                <p><span class="text-dark">Non-stop binge<br>watchers</span></p>


            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2" style="background-color: grey;">
            <div>
                <h4>STANDARD</h4>
                <br>
            </div>

            <div class="tx">
                <p> <span class="text-light"> 100 Mbps</span></p>
                <p> <span class="text-light">✅ </span></p>
                <p> <span class="text-light">₹799 </span></p>

                <p><span class="text-light">Small family with <br>light usage </span></p>


            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2" style="background-color: grey;">
            <div>
                <h4>BASIC</h4>
                <br>
            </div>

            <div class="tx">
                <p> <span class="text-light"> 40 Mbps</span></p>
                <p> <span class="text-light">✅ </span></p>
                <p> <span class="text-light">₹499 </span></p>

                <p><span class="text-light">Individuals<br>with light usage </span></p>


            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-2 text-light" style="background-color: grey;">
            <br>
            <div> Streaing <br>apps</div>
            <br>

        </div>



        <div class="col-6 text-light" style="background-color: rgb(49, 49, 49);">
            <br>
            <div>Amazon-prime + Disnep hotstar</div>
            <br>
        </div>

        <div class="col-2 text-light" style="background-color: rgb(49, 49, 49);">
            <br>
            <span style="font-size: 21px;">X</span>
            <br>

        </div>
        <div class="col-2 text-light" style="background-color: rgb(49, 49, 49);">
            <br>
            <span style="font-size: 21px;">X</span>
            <br>

        </div>


    </div>
</div>






















<!-- Bootstrap JavaScript Libraries -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Someone please help me out with** `Source Code`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here could be a good start...
Toggle to full-page to show result

INFO: It use [Bootstrap icons](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/) and BS grid system only and [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) to get the "special border"

```css
@import url("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.7.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css");
.h-20 {
  height: 20%;
}

.shadow-lg {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1rem 3rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)!important
}

.path {
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 27% 68%, 0 100%, 0 0);
  box-shadow: 0 1rem 3rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid bg-dark vh-100 text-center">
    <div class="row h-75">
        <div class="col-2 text-white">
            <div class="row h-20"></div>
            <div class="row h-20 align-items-center">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <i class="bi bi-speedometer2"></i> Speed
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row h-20 align-items-center">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <i class="bi bi-bar-chart-fill"></i> Unlimited <br> data
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row h-20 align-items-center">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <i class="bi bi-currency-exchange"></i> Monthly <br> rental
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row h-20 align-items-center">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <i class="bi bi-people-fill"></i> Who is <br> it for ?
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 bg-danger shadow-lg">
            <div class="row h-20 align-items-center bg-white path">
                <div class="col-12">
                    INFINTY
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row h-20 align-items-center text-white">
                <div class="col-12">
                    Speed
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row h-20 align-items-center text-white">
                <div class="col-12">
                    Unlimited <br> data
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row h-20 align-items-center text-white">
                <div class="col-12">
                    Monthly <br> rental
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row h-20 align-items-center text-white">
                <div class="col-12">
                    Who is <br> it for ?
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 bg-danger shadow-lg">
            <div class="row h-20 align-items-center bg-white path">
                <div class="col-12">
                    PROFESSIONAL
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row h-20 align-items-center text-white">
                <div class="col-12">
                    Speed
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row h-20 align-items-center text-white">
                <div class="col-12">
                    Unlimited <br> data
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row h-20 align-items-center text-white">
                <div class="col-12">
                    Monthly <br> rental
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row h-20 align-items-center text-white">
                <div class="col-12">
                    Who is <br> it for ?
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 bg-white shadow-lg">
            <div class="row h-20 align-items-center bg-danger path">
                <div class="col-12 text-white">
                    ENTERTAINMENT
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row h-20 align-items-center">
                <div class="col-12">
                    Speed
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row h-20 align-items-center">
                <div class="col-12">
                    Unlimited <br> data
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row h-20 align-items-center">
                <div class="col-12">
                    Monthly <br> rental
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row h-20 align-items-center">
                <div class="col-12">
                    Who is <br> it for ?
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 shadow-lg">
            <div class="row h-20 align-items-center bg-white path">
                <div class="col-12">
                    STANDARD
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row h-20 align-items-center text-white">
                <div class="col-12">
                    Speed
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row h-20 align-items-center text-white">
                <div class="col-12">
                    Unlimited <br> data
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row h-20 align-items-center text-white">
                <div class="col-12">
                    Monthly <br> rental
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row h-20 align-items-center text-white">
                <div class="col-12">
                    Who is <br> it for ?
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 shadow-lg">
            <div class="row h-20 align-items-center bg-white path">
                <div class="col-12">
                    BASICS
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row h-20 align-items-center text-white">
                <div class="col-12">
                    Who is <br> it for ?
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row h-20 align-items-center text-white">
                <div class="col-12">
                    Who is <br> it for ?
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row h-20 align-items-center text-white">
                <div class="col-12">
                    Who is <br> it for ?
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row h-20 align-items-center text-white">
                <div class="col-12">
                    Who is <br> it for ?
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row h-25">
        <div class="col-2 bg-secondary"></div>
        <div class="col-6 shadow-lg"></div>
        <div class="col-2 shadow-lg"></div>
        <div class="col-2 shdaow-lg"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess this is I already created I need  those complicated borders! like crossing each other can you help me with that please. and I guess it's not responsive I need responsive too.

Comment: @SushantUniversity Border added, for the responsive, you can do it yoursel, simply use bootstrap breakpoint :)

Comment: Sure I'll make it responsive by my own!